# calling web service using basicHttpBinding from classic asp file

Tags: web-services, soap, asp-classic, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF web service that connects to most applications using wsHttpBinding.  I have to connect to this web service from a classic asp file.  From what I have read and tried, I need to use basicHttpBinding to do this.  It is SOAP 1.1 and to use webhttpbinding, I would have to change the web service interface by adding `[WebGet]` and this is not an option. So I added the basicHttpBinding to the web service.

I run the asp file using a console application. When it is run, I get the error:

> The message with  Action 'urn:http://tempuri.org/IPaging/TestMethod'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver,  due to a ContractFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher.  This may be because of either a contract
>   mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver)  or a
>   binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.   Check
>   that sender and receiver have the same contract and the  same binding
>   (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

I don't see where I am going wrong.  I have the URL set to call the basic binding.  The SOAP message is using 1.1 and I believe it is correct.

Why is there a mismatch between the sender and receiver?
There is no app.config file on the client side to define the connection.  It is just 1 asp file.  If I need that, how does the asp file read the app.config file?

Config file below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="PagingService.Paging" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPaging" contract="PagingService.IPaging">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPaging" contract="PagingService.IPaging">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/PagingService/Service1/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPaging" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaging">
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">      
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>      
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I want to call the method `TestMethod` from the paging service from the classic asp file
This is the WSDL that describes the TestMethod:

```
<wsdl:operation name="TestMethod">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPaging/TestMethod" message="tns:IPaging_TestMethod_InputMessage" /> 
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPaging/TestMethodResponse" message="tns:IPaging_TestMethod_OutputMessage" /> 
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="TestMethod">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPaging/TestMethod" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

This is how the basicHttpBinding is defined in the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaging" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IPaging">
<soap:address location="http://<server>:<port>/Fld1/PagingService.Paging.svc/basic" /> 
</wsdl:port>
```

This is the asp code that calls the web service:

```
Dim NS, NS_SOAP, NS_SOAPENC, NS_XSI, NS_XSD
NS = "urn:http://tempuri.org/"
NS_SOAP = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
NS_SOAPENC = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding"
NS_XSI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
NS_XSD = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

'Using basicHttpBinding
URL = "http://<server><port>/Fld1/PagingService.Paging.svc/basic"

' XML DOM objects.
Dim DOM, Envelope, Body, Operation, Param 

' Creates an XML DOM object.
Set objXmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0") 
objXmlDoc.async = false

Set Envelope = objXmlDoc.createNode(1, "soap:Envelope", NS_SOAP)
Envelope.setAttribute "xmlns:soapenc", NS_SOAPENC
Envelope.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", NS_XSI
Envelope.setAttribute "xmlns:xsd", NS_XSD
objXmlDoc.appendChild Envelope
Set Body = objXmlDoc.createNode(1, "Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
Envelope.appendChild Body 
Set Operation = objXmlDoc.createNode(1, "TestMethod", NS)
Body.appendChild Operation 

Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
httpRequest.Open "POST", URL, False    
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"  
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "urn:http://tempuri.org/IPaging/TestMethod"
httpRequest.send objXmlDoc.xml

strStatusText = "Status: " & httpRequest.status & vbCrLf & "Status text: " & httpRequest.statusText
Response.Write(vbCrLf & strStatusText & vbCrLf)  
Response.Write(httpRequest.responseText)

Set Operation = Nothing
Set Body = Nothing
Set Envelope = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.
Removed `urn:` from NS constant and SOAPAction strings and it worked.